# Google AndroidPublisher API batch

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I think that the Batch method of the Android Publisher doesn't work.

I'm using the Java library:

```
'com.google.apis:google-api-services-androidpublisher:v2-rev16-1.19.1'
```

The error I get is:

```
SEVERE: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "[entry[0].inappproductsInsertRequest.package_name]",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "Required parameter: [entry[0].inappproductsInsertRequest.package_name]",
    "reason" : "required"
  } ],
  "message" : "Required parameter: [entry[0].inappproductsInsertRequest.package_name]"
}
```

I'm using the Java API and so I'm pretty sure I'm filling in all the fields, including the InAppProducts packageName.

What puzzles me is that the InappproductsInsertRequest class doens't have any "package_name" field. And of course, the name "package_name" seems weird with the underscore in the middle, while the rest of the API uses "packageName".

It seems to me that this API is not much tested and this is a bug.